# "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" but no static variable or method

Tags: java, bluej

I have to do an assignment (in Java, using BlueJ) and in one part of this assignment, I need to have a 'Move' method in the PlayerShip class. According to the assignment instructions, I also need to have this same method in the Gun class, and the method in the PlayerShip class must call the method in the Gun class twice. For reference, I have provided the code for my Gun class:

```
    public class Gun
{
    private int position;
    private int power;
    private int points;
    private boolean justFired;

    public Gun(int initialPosition, int initialPower) 
    {
        position = initialPosition;
        power = initialPower;
    }

    public void Move(int distance)
    {
        position = position + distance;
    }
}
```

And this is the code for my PlayerShip class:

```
public class PlayerShip
{
    private int position;

    public PlayerShip()
    {
        position = Global.promptInt("Player position: ");
        Gun gun1 = new Gun(position - 1, 5);
        Gun gun2 = new Gun(position + 1, 5);
    }

    public void Move(int distance)
    {
        position = position + distance;

        Gun.Move(distance);

    }
}
```

Now the issue is, I keep getting an error:

> non-static method Move(Int) cannot be reference from a static context

when I try to call the Move() method in the Gun class, from the Move() method in the PlayerShip class. I don't know why I am getting this error because none of the variables or methods are static, and I am out of ideas so any help is appreciated

Edit: The marking software is very rigid and does not accept my code if the variables are static

Comment: Sorry if my question seems vague or confusing, if anyone needs any clarification please feel free to ask and I will do my best to better convey my issue :)

Comment: "I don't know why I am getting this error because none of the variables or methods are static"  That's the reason *why* you are getting the error -- `Gun.Move(distance);` is an attempt to call `Move` in a static context, as opposed to calling it on an *instance* of `Gun`

Comment: Hi George, that was quick haha thank you. Another problem I should have mentioned is that the marking software is quite rigid and the variable 'position' cannot be static (I tried making it static and the software didn't accept it). So should I somehow try to make the 'distance' static?

Comment: @JaffarAli No, *avoid* static, as it is a class global scope. Invoke the method on an instance. You need to convert the method variables of ` gun` into a variable of the object.

Comment: As George already explained the problem is the attempt to statically call the `Move` method of the `Gun` within the `Move` method of your `PlayerShip` class. You are creating two instances of `Gun` in the constructor. So you could assign those instances to fields of the class `PlayerShip` and then call the `Move` method on each of those fields.

Comment: @M.leRutte Sorry, like I said I am a noob at this. So when you say "invoke the method on an instance," are you talking about invoking it on gun1 and gun2 individually? I have considered this but I do not actually know how to put this into code so uhh, again, any help is appreciated

Comment: @GeorgWittberger I think I understand what you are saying, do you mean to assign the instances of `Gun` to variables in the `PlayerShip` class and then call the `Move()` method in `PlayerShip` class? That makes sense but the assignment specification says that "the method [in the `PlayerShip` class] should make two calls (one for each gun) to the `Move()` method in the `Gun` class" so would there be any way to achieve this or should I just ignore it and do what what you said?

Comment: @JaffarAli take a look at the current answers. Comments are not intended for answering a question.

Comment: I agree with Sebastiaan, please see his answer. It is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Ok thank you all haha, still getting the hang of all this (coding AND stack overflow) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Move method you call Gun.Move.

Gun is a class rather than an object. Therefore, you're trying to call Move on the 'blueprint' of a Gun rather than an actual Gun object.

When you instantiate your PlayerShip class, you create two Gun instances. If i'm right in assuming that you want the PlayerShip class to 'have' two guns. You can give the PlayerShip class two private gun variables so they are accessible to the move method.

```
public class PlayerShip
{
private int position;
private Gun gun1;
private Gun gun2;

// rest of code 

}
```

From this you can then access your gun objects that are owned by your PlayerShip object.

Create the constructor and move method as such:

```
public PlayerShip()
{
    position = Global.promptInt("Player position: ");
    gun1 = new Gun(position - 1, 5);
    gun2 = new Gun(position + 1, 5);
}

public void Move(int distance)
{
    position = position + distance;

    gun1.Move(distance);
    gun1.Move(distance);

}
```

You were receiving a static reference error as you were attempting to call a method on Gun class rather than the individual instances.

The **static** keyword means that it is the same for every instance of an object.

Hope this was helpful, it is difficult to start understanding how objects work at the start.

Keep practicing!

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. And I will keep practising!

Answer (score 0):

```
Gun.Move(distance);
```

is the way you call static methods, which `Move()` isn't.

you want an instance of `Gun` to call the `Move()` method.

such as

```
Gun gun = new Gun();
gun.Move()
```